# Не работает команда Java-version

Tags: java

Установил JDK 19, добавил переменную в переменные среды (Windows 10 ОС),но при вводе команды "Java - version" выходит ошибка "Unrecognized option: -
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit."
В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

У вас банальная опечатка при вводе команды, пробел не ставится в названии опции
`java -version`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]